# Why only first form is validated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Please refer to the following fiddle.

```
<form action="http://someurl.com/" id="test-form-1" method="post" name="test-form-1">
  <input class="test-domainurl" type="url"> <input class="test-order-button" type="submit" value="Continue to Order">
</form>
<form action="http://someurl.com/" id="test-form-2" method="post" name="test-form-2">
  <input class="test-domainurl" type="url"> <input class="test-order-button" type="submit" value="Continue to Order">
</form>


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".test-order-button").click(function() {
        $("#test-form-1").validate({});
        $("#test-form-2").validate({});
        $(".test-domainurl").rules("add", {
            required: true
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vak87/

I'm not sure why only first form is validated?

Any ideas and suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You are improperly using the `.validate()` method. It should only be called _once_ on DOM ready to initialize the plugin. There is absolutely no need to wrap it inside a click handler when the button click is automatically captured by the plugin. Please refer to the [jquery-validate wiki page on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` within the css selector, and use `parent()` and `siblings('.test-domainurl')` to find the elements that correspond to each button.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".test-order-button").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().validate({});
        $(this).siblings('.test-domainurl').rules("add", {
            required: true
        });
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vak87/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment about your code not working in IE7 and IE8...

1) You absolutely do not need to enclose `.validate()` within a `click` event handler.  The `.validate()` method is only the *initialization* for the plugin, not the testing method.  The `.validate()` method only needs to be called *once* on DOM ready and any subsequent call is always ignored.  The validation test is performed because the click is automatically captured by the plugin.

2) When attaching the `.rules()` method to a jQuery object that contains more than one element, you must enclose it within a jQuery `.each()`.  Otherwise, the `.rules()` method would only assign the rule to the first matching element.

This is the proper way...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#test-form-1").validate({});  // intialize plugin on first form

    $("#test-form-2").validate({});  // intialize plugin on second form

    $(".test-domainurl").each(function() {  // select applicable inputs
        $(this).rules("add", {              // apply the rule to each selected input
            required: true
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you  for your detailed explanation. I understand it properly. And also updated with your answer which works fine. However, it still doesn't work with IE 7 & IE8. I have latest version of jQuery 1.11.1 and latest Validation plugin. Any idea / suggestions?

Comment: @Krunal, I know this plugin works fine in IE7 & IE8 because I use it all the time.  My guess is that you're testing it in IE9 or 10 within "compatibility mode".  Compatibility mode is not an emulator.  You must always test in the real browser.  MS provides free VPC hard drive images for testing each version of Explorer.  See: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575 as one example.

Comment: @Sparksy Yes, I've tested it on Compatibility mode. I have a separate setup as well, will check it there too. I'm sure it will work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the validate plugin, but my guess is that the selector is being limited to the first match within the plugin. If you add the rules individually it seems to work.

Example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".test-order-button").click(function() {
        $("#test-form-1").validate({});
        $("#test-form-2").validate({});
        $(".test-domainurl").each(function(index, el) {
            $(el).rules("add", {
                required: true
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Got it fixed. I should have refer to its documentation first. I added required into the field and its working. However, I'm still not sure why the earlier code doesn't worked? Any idea would be helpful to understand its behavior. Thanks

Comment: @Krunal it looks like `rules` should be an option of the validate prototype